# UTC to Central Time conversion

Tags: time, utc, dst, alteryx

I have a dataset in which the time stamp is UTC. I want to convert it into Central Time (CDT/CST), including the daylight saving time switches(CDT= UTC-5, CST=UTC-6). I cannot use `[DateTimetoLocal]` function because our Alteryx server runs on GMT. If I use this function the the time stamp will get converted into GMT instead on CDT/CST.

How can I convert this time stamp in Central Time (CDT/CST), taking daylight savings into consideration?

Comment: Is this Java or another computer language?

Comment: This same question was asked and answered at the Alteryx community site: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/UTC-to-Central-Time-conversion/m-p/623417#M141106